# Tika pass parser info during incremental read

Tags: java, parsing, apache-tika

I know Tika has a very nice wrapper that let's me get a Reader back from parsing a file like so:

```
Reader parsedReader = tika.parse(in);
```

However, if I use this, I cannot specify the parser that I want and the metadata that I want to pass in. For example, I would want to pass in extra info like which handler, parser, and context to use, but I can't do it if I use this method. As far as I know, it's the only one that let's me get a Reader instance back and read incrementally instead of getting the entire parsed string back.

Example of things I want to include:

```
        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, fileName); //This aids in the content detection
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        context.set(Parser.class, parser);
        parser.parse(is, handler, metadata, context);
```

However, calling parse on a parser directly does not return a reader, and the only option I have(noticed in the docs) is to return a fully parsed string, which might not be great for memory usage. I know I can limit the string that is returned, but I want to stay away from that as I wanto the fully parsed info, but in incremental fashion. Best of both world, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the many great things about [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) is that it's open source, so you can see how it works. The class for the [Tika facade](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/Tika.java) you're using is [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/Tika.java)

The key bit of that class for your interest is this bit:

```
public Reader parse(InputStream stream, Metadata metadata)
        throws IOException {
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
    context.set(Parser.class, parser);
    return new ParsingReader(parser, stream, metadata, context);
}
```

You see there how Tika is taking a parser and a stream, and processing it to a Reader. Do something similar and you're set. Alternately, write your own ContentHandler and call that directly for full control!